# Find Axis/Angle of one Vector3 relative to another

Tags: libgdx

This seemed like an easy and well documented task.
I have two Vector3 objects representing locations of models.

I wish to point an object located at one Vector3 location so it looks at the other Vector3 location.

Initially I looked at a few sources like;
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/

Which seems to document the method as finding the dot product for the angle and the cross product for the axis.

Looking over the Quaternion source code It seems that the "setFromCross" does this for me.
So I tried the following code;

```java
Vector3 thisPoint = this.transState.position.cpy();
Vector3 targetPoint = target.transState.position.cpy();

targetPoint.nor();
thisPoint.nor();

Quaternion result = new Quaternion();               
result.setFromCross(targetPoint,thisPoint);
```

This seemed simply but didn't work - clearly pointed the wrong way.
I then tried implementing it manually;

```java
float theirDotProduct = thisPoint.dot(targetPoint); 
float angle = (float) Math.acos(theirDotProduct);

Vector3 theirCrossProduct = thisPoint.crs(targetPoint); 
Vector3 axis = theirCrossProduct.nor();

//now make a Quaternion from it and return
Quaternion result = new Quaternion();
result.setFromAxisRad(axis, angle);
```

Also didn't work, again, points clearly the wrong way (and not 90degrees off or anything by a fixed amount, the relationship between the direction and the vectors seems wrong)

---

For reference I am using a system where my models store their location and rotation as vector3s and Quaterions - for animations sake I am only converting to a Matrix at the very last step.
The exact code used to take that Quaterion and set the models rotation is;

```java
/** lookat the target models vector3 location (currently doesn't work) **/
public void lookAt(AnimatableModelInstance target){

Quaternion angle = getAngleTo(target);          
setToRotation(angle);

}

/*** Set the rotation. If doing a more complex change make a PosRotScale and call setTransform **/
public void setToRotation(Quaternion angle) {       
    transState.rotation.set(angle);
    sycnTransform();
}

public void sycnTransform() {
        super.transform.set(transState.position, transState.rotation, transState.scale);
}
```

This seems to work fine for all the other rotational animations I am doing so I don't think the mistake is in that area.

I am guessing its some basic step or concept I am missing here.

Thanks,
-Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I'm not familiar with libgdx. I my answer is not helpful or plainly wrong, maybe I can grab this [peer pressure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge.</sub>

It seems that there's a misunderstanding concerning the angle that is computed. You said that you are storing the *position* of the objects. Then, you are computing the dot product

```
float theirDotProduct = thisPoint.dot(targetPoint);
```

However, the angle that you are computing from this dot product has nothing to do with the angle that is necessary to align one object in the direction of the other. The angle that you are computing there is basically *the angle between the lines that start at the origin and pass through the object positions* (as also shown in the image on the site that you linked to).

---

I assume that there is a default orientation of the object, where the rotation angle is zero, and where the object "points along the x-axis", for example. Then, in order to align such an object so that it "points into the direction of another object", you have to set the orientation of this object as follows:

You have to compute the difference between the objects - like a line drawn between the objects. Then, you can compute the angle between this line and the x-axis.

[image]

This is the angle that is required for rotating object A so that it points towards object B.

The *axis* of rotation is computed by taking the cross product, but once again not between the *positions* of the objects, but between the x-axis and the *difference* of the object positions.

---

The code, involving some guesswork about the libgdx usage, could thus roughly look like this:

```
Vector3 thisPoint = ...;
Vector3 targetPoint = ...;

Vector3 difference = targetPoint.sub(thisPoint);

if (difference.len() < someSmallEpsilon) 
{
    // Objects are at the same location - can't
    // sensibly compute a direction to look at
    return;
}
Vector3 direction = difference.nor() 

Vector3 xAxis = new Vector3(1,0,0);

float dotProduct = xAxis.dot(direction); 
float angle = (float) Math.acos(dotProduct);

if (angle < someSmallEpsilon)
{
    // Angle is already right. Nothing to do
    return;
}

Vector3 axis = xAxis.crs(direction).nor();
Quaternion result = new Quaternion();
result.setFromAxisRad(axis, angle);
```

(don't pin me down to the signs - it might be that the angle (or axis) may have be to negated - but this should be the basic approach)

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it explained it perfectly, and you pointed out a few other things I overlooked.
Your LibGDX code is essentially all correct from what I see.
(sorry, you wont be getting your peer pressure badge today!)

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as an axis/angle between two locations. Calculating the rotation of two vectors would only be useful if they have the same location (origin).

Keep in mind that vectors don't represent a location, but rather how to get from the origin to a specific location (although that's practically probably the same thing in your case, it is mathematically very different). You probably already tried to use this because you're normalizing the vectors (which in your code actually removes quite some important information).

Calculating the angle between locations would get you the rotation between those locations relative to the origin (location 0,0,0). In other words: it will get you the rotation the `thisPoint` vector should be rotated *around 0,0,0* to match the *direction* (not *length*) of `targetPoint`. Note the use of *direction* and *length*, which is another way to say the same thing. E.g. a vector of x:5,y:0,z:0 has a direction of x:1,y:0,z:0 and a length of 5.

In your case you want the vector (especially the *direction*, but you dont need the *length*) of `targetPoint` relative to `thisPoint`. Or in other words: if you start at `thisPoint` to which direction should you go to get to `targetPoint`. This can be easily calculated by subtracting the vectors and then normalizing the result. Normalizing is required to remove the *length* (set it to 1), so we only keep the *direction*.

```
Vector3 direction = new Vector3();
direction.set(targetPoint).sub(thisPoint).nor();
```

Now we have the *direction* you want your model to look at. To calculate the *rotation* we will first need to know where it is looking at when it is unrotated. This obviously depends on your model and how it is modeled. Let say it's base vector (the unrotated direction) is `Vector3.X`, then you can use:

```
result.setFromCross(Vector3.X,t direction);
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it.
I did actually try subtraction at one point to get it relative to 0,0,0, but I think I got the rest mixed up. I was just stabbing in the dark at that point.
Thanks, this has cleared a lot up. (and your previous advice is proving very useful still)
I will however accept Marcos as the answer, as the diagramm helped, and I overlooked the possibility of the vectors being identical.

Comment: Cant find a `setCrossFrom` method